# Will not assign values individually to method

Tags: c#

Trying to complete an assignment for class and I can get correct output when assigning the parameters together but when trying to assign the values individually I can't get a price. I have a feeling it's an extremely easy fix but I've been doing assignments all day and my brain feels like jello. Not looking for an answer so much as a hint to push my to the correct answer. Thanks!

````
using static System.Console;
using System;
class PhotoDemo
{
   static void Main()
   {
      Photo standardPhoto = new Photo();
      standardPhoto.Width = 8;
      standardPhoto.Height = 9;
      WriteLine(standardPhoto.ToString());

      Photo customPhoto = new Photo(10, 12);
      WriteLine(customPhoto.ToString());

      MattedPhoto mattedPhoto = new MattedPhoto(8, 9, "Blue");
      WriteLine(mattedPhoto.ToString());

      FramedPhoto framedPhoto = new FramedPhoto(8, 9, "Wood", "Modern");
      WriteLine(framedPhoto.ToString());
   }
}

public class Photo
{
  public Photo(){}
  public int Width{get; set;}
  public int Height{get; set;}
  protected double Price{get; set;}

  public Photo(int width, int height)
  {
    Width = width;
    Height = height;
    if(width == 8 && height == 10)
    {
      Price = 3.99;
    }
    else if(Width == 10 && Height == 12)
    {
      Price = 5.99;
    }
    else
    {
      Price = 9.99;
    }
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    string output = String.Format("Width: {0}, Height: {1}, Price: {2}", Width, Height, Price.ToString("C"));
    return output;
  }
}

public class MattedPhoto : Photo
{
  public MattedPhoto(){}
  public string Color {get; set;}
  public MattedPhoto(int width, int height, string color) : base(width, height)
  {
    width = Width;
    height = Height;
    color = Color;

    if(width == 8 && height == 10)
    {
      Price = 3.99 + 10;
    }
    else if(width == 10 && height == 12)
    {
      Price = 5.99 + 10;
    }
    else
    {
      Price = 9.99 + 10;
    }
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    string output = String.Format("Width: {0}, Height: {1}, Price: {2}, Color: {3}", Width, Height, Price.ToString("C"), Color);
    return output;
  }
}

public class FramedPhoto : Photo
{
  public FramedPhoto(){}
  public string Material{get; set;}
  public string Style{get; set;}

  public FramedPhoto(int width, int height, string material, string style) : base(width, height)
  {
    width = Width;
    height = Height;
    material = Material;
    style = Style;

    if(width == 8 && height == 10)
    {
      Price = 3.99 + 25;
    }
    else if(width == 10 && height == 12)
    {
      Price = 5.99 + 25;
    }
    else
    {
      Price = 9.99 + 25;
    }
  }


  public override string ToString()
  {
    string output = String.Format("Width: {0}, Height: {1}, Price: {2}, Material: {3}, Style: {4}", Width, Height, Price.ToString("C"), Material, Style);
    return output;
  }
}```
````

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please tell us what input you are giving to your program and what output you expect.  It's not clear what you mean when you say _when trying to assign the values individually_

Comment: You're only doing your price calculations within your object's constructor. If you then change the properties later the price won't be recalculated.

Comment: Sorry about that! I just realized that was the previous version of the code and the new code is where I'm having troubles. In standardPhoto, when I assign values individually it gives me a price of 0.00. Unlike customPhoto when I assign both values at the same time it gives me the correct price.

Comment: Note that each of your `ToString()` overrides have one too many arguments being passed to `String.Format`.... You should remove `this.GetType()`, or use it in the string format.

Comment: Is this really the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Price calculation is doing only in the constructors with parameters (so only when you create an object). When you use parameter-less one, then the price isn't calculated (even if you set width and height later). You can:

- create a separate method which takes width and height as parameters and recalculates price
- modify price getter, to automatically recalculate price every time you ask for it